# Should I repeat the title in the question body?

Tags: discussion, questions, title

For example, suppose this question, I have stated my question in the title of it. Should I repeat it here?

There are some questions which put all the question details in the title, then few things remains to be expanded in the body if they don't actually restate the title again. Maybe this approach is good for the answerer to immediately understand the question and click on it, or maybe the OP purposely do it to attract more attention to the question.

Some people put a summary in title and elaborate it in the question. Some continue the body from the point the title ends, and the title seems like an introduction statement. Some prefer to repeat the question at the end of the question body to emphasize what exactly they want.

Some think if they don't repeat and restate the title in the body, their question might be closed as unclear or lacking the problem statement.

What is the best approach to trade off the information you put in the title and the question, and where in the body should I restate the title, if at all.

Comment: What would be the added value?

Comment: MSE post: [Questions in titles need to be repeated, why?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173271/questions-in-titles-need-to-be-repeated-why)

Comment: What I have seen that is truly confusing is a question in the title but a _different_ one in the body.

Comment: Over 6 downvotes for a great question? I had the same question in mind. Does it make me an evil user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Repeat: no.**

But the question title should be the summary of the question.

I dislike the awful manner of posting the question in the title, and the code dump in the body.

For me, the question body must be understandable per se. I click the title if I think the question may be worthy it, but if it's impossible to understand what's actually asked there without looking at the title, I'll vote to close as 'unclear as you are asking'.

It may sound harsh, but if someone is unwilling to invest an extra minute in writing a good question, I don't think he deserve the community to invest their time in answering.

**In your case**, if you're body would be like that:

> what do you think

I'd immediately vote to close. Now it's better, but far from perfect. Not only the body being the continuation of title doesn't met my style, but in my opinion it's way too brief. If you want to start discussion on meta, you should provide some background. Writing a question and that's it is more like chat.

Comment: See also: [What should I write in the question body if the title already explains everything?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145019/what-should-i-write-in-the-question-body-if-the-title-already-explains-everythin)

Comment: @Bart thanks, the answer from Time Traveling Bobby is what was in my mind, only he has written it 10 times better :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. But do it at the end.
And instead of copying it verbatim you should elaborate and expand it.

Browsing Stack Overflow is not my main job, so I'm usually not very concentrated when I do it. So there is a good chance that I can't remember the question when I'm finished reading your posting. Especially if it's a complicated problem.

A question structure like this would be ideal for me:

- short description of the problem
- description of the context in which the problem happens
- code
- question and what you tried to solve the problem

---

Error messages that only exist in the subject are even worse. It's hard to copy text if it's part of a link.

Comment: “You should elaborate.” That’s asking for junk. I prefer perfect questions.

Answer (score 0):

What's the point?

Or, to answer your question: Nope. There's no added value.
People that open your question usually do so by clicking the question's title. That means they probably read it already.

Comment: I felt so, but have seen some questions which restate the title in the question